# Spring Web MVC on Tomcat and STS - The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, spring, macos, spring-mvc, tomcat

Using Spring Tool Suite (STS) and Tomcat v8.0, I followed [this](https://manueljordan.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/creating-a-spring-web-mvc-project-with-springsource-tool-suite/) tutorial to study up and get some knowledge about Spring. My intention is to display a simple "Hello World" or something, and build on from there.

Here are my codes. Most of these files were automatically created upon starting the project:

*HomeController.java*:

```
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );
        model.addAttribute("welcomeMessage", "Spring MVC trial: Welcome!");

        return "home";
    }
}
```

*home.jsp*:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Hello world!  
</h1>

<P>  The time on the server is ${serverTime}. </P>
<P> ${welcomeMessage} </P>
</body>
</html>
```

*web.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My only deviation from the tutorial was the use of a Tomcat v8.0 server.

**The Problem:**

This is the result of the internal browser, set to (by default, upon running the project):
http://localhost:8080/spring/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp

[image]

That's what I get upon running the project. From what I gather from the log, the server works fine.

However, as per the tutorial, I'm supposed to get a:

```
"Welcome home! The client locale is XXXXX"
```

in the console log, which I'm not seeing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request should be `http://localhost:8080/{applicationname}`

Bacause of `return "home"` your `HomeController` will automaticaly call a JSP file named `home.jsp`

---

**How to find the real application name for http request?**

1. Double click on your server inside **Servers** window of STS. In this example it is *Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.1*

[image: Double click on Pivotal tc Server...]

2. Web Modules file is opened now. Click then on **Modules** and you will see the request application name, in this example it is */mvc*:

[image]

So the browser url is now http://localhost:8080/mvc

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. Running the project automatically points to that page. Typing in `http://localhost:8080/samplemvcproject` leads to the same result, however.

Comment: Mine returned /spring. When I typed that in, it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Facing the same issue and this solution does not work for me.